# Properly push NSViews

Tags: cocoa, resize, window, nsview

I had a great system (It worked but was probably **not** the correct way to accomplish the task) going to animating one NSView over another. The user clicked a button and an NSView flew in over the other "replacing" it. The problem came in with window resizing. Due to the way I set it up, one view was sitting in a non-visible location and animating in with `animator`, resizing was nearly impossible. I also tried [this](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/03/03/core-animation-tutorial-wizard-dialog-with-transitions/) which seemed promising but failed to deliver a method (and I couldn't come up with one) for handeling window resizes. So how can one accomplish the seemingly simple task of swapping views with a nice transition? Sorry for the long winded question and hopefully I explained the system I had clearly enough.

Thanks for any help/advice

Answer (score 1):

Just add your controller as the window's delegate and implement the `windowWillResize:toSize:` delegate method.

In your implementation of the method you should set the size of your off-screen view appropriately.